# Is it possible to run a script on an Android App by clicking a button on a site?

Tags: android, url, run-script

Is it possible for a button on my site to run a script on an app I've build on my Android phone?

I've just recently started learning C# and Unity, so a step by step explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Loading your website using a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) you would be able to create a bridge to your app using [addJavascriptInterface(Object, String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)). This allows the Java object's methods to be accessed from JavaScript.

Comment: Hello Diego, thanks for your answer! I´m not sure if I got it right, but in this solution I would have to open my site from a display within my app, correct? What I'm looking for is some way to visit my site though a traditional web browser, click on a button and run a script in my app ( if it's possible for the button to open the app first and then run the script, it would be even better). I apologize if I didn't get it right. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

yes - by using `android:scheme` in `data` element in an `intent-filter` on your activity.  see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html for details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I´m pretty new at programming, I´m having some difficulty to understand the procedure. I already added the intent-filter to the Android Manifest of my app as show in (http://www.eduardo-cg.com/androidmanifest). The idea was that the button on the site would link to "www.eduardo-cg.com/test", and this URL would trigger the script in the app. Besides the intent-filter on the manifest, do I have to write any code at the URL? Thanks.

Comment: at a quick glance at your manifest it looks correct.  you should now get an `onNewIntent` in your activity

Comment: Well, I'm definitely lost in here... if it's not too much, could you tell me how and where should I implement `onNewIntent`? I've built my app on Unity, so I'm not sure if this changes anything in this procedure. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting closer here... I couldn't figure out how to use `onNewIntent`, but I was able to open my app from the button at my site by writing `<a href="intent://www.eduardo-cg.com/test#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.vizAR.OppaAR;end;">Open App</a>` in it. Great! But I still need to be able to run different scripts on the app from different buttons on the site... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use push messaging. You can implement FCM or MQTT. Then, your app can subscribe to a topic, and when the button gets pressed by a browser pointed at your site, you just publish any content to the topic.

Comment: Hello Mark, this may be a interesting way, I'll see if I can manage to implement it. I saw that Firebase have a SDK for Unity, which may help me to get through it. Thanks.

Comment: I have a restaurant menu app. The client can push down menu updates from the website to their tablets. I use the Android Device ID as the push message topic in the push message to target the specific tablets. You can use FCM (friebase cloud messaging to do this- Google has some FCM sample apps). I use the open source MQTT to do it. Then all you need a broker running on a server to manage the messages- I use AWS and the open source Mosquitto broker. There is a tutorial in my book Android Software Development, and MQTT tutorials online. Good luck. Not trivial but once working, a powerful setup.